# Run xUnit with TFS 2015 vNext build

Tags: tfs, win-universal-app, xunit, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to run xUnit tests for UWP with TFS 2015 vNext build?
I try to do it with my local build Agent with it running in interactive mode.
When test needs to be done, the UWP test app runs but no tests discovered.
Is it supported to run this tests?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/01/run-xunit-in-hosted-team-foundation-service/

Comment: @KenTucker this is about old build style, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming you have installed xunit via Nuget and your packages are at the root level of your sources folder, you just need to set the **Path to Custom Test Adapters** to your packages folder.

In my case: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\packages` - adjust as you need to.

[image]

Comment: Didn't help, got "Warning: No test is available" when running appx with xUnit.